# Wordpress if current page is parent menu or submenu?

Tags: wordpress, parent-child, sidebar

I have this sidebar that is only relevant when the current page is a parent menu item or a submenu item
Is there any way i can make an `if statement` to check this in Wordpress? I did find some info on this but none of them works in my sidebar.php.

Any ideas on this? Thanks

Comment: Something like this - count( get_children([post_parent => 'id']) ) == 0

Comment: hi, thank you. Is there any way you can further put this in code? Im quite new with this.. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting this line at the top of your sidebar.php file, then surrounding the code with this if statment

```
if(0 != count( get_children( array(post_parent => $post->ID) ) ) ) { 
   <sidebar code> 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. See my updated question. Guess i made a mistake in the terms ive used. Its about submenu items.. guess those are not childs?